# Android Picasso store files or use cache

Tags: android, imageview, picasso, android-library, android-file

I'm using `Picasso` to initially download images of products to my app from a `server`. Since the images aren't changing nearly at all for a certain product, I save the images to the disk from the `ImageView`. In the app I have to display these images all over again in different sizes. To do so I'm using `Picasso` again, loading the saved file into an `ImageView` and do `fit().centercrop()` so I don't get `any OutofMemory issues`.

Since `Picasso` is also capable of using `OkHttp`'s cache and doing the caching by its own, I want to know:

> - Are there any advantages about letting `Picasso` do the caching, over saving it to storage manually and handing it over again to `Picasso` later?
> - And would it be a good way to store the shrinked image (after using `.fit()`) as a new file so the calculation hasn't to be done all the time.

Comment: you want to clear `Picasso Clear Memory` ?

Comment: I don't want the app to make any more request to the server after the image is downloaded once and to provide the image even when the app is offline.

Comment: Then i think u a stored all image's in your local machine .

Comment: Are there any best pratices to do so? Currently I'm taking the bitmap from the first ImageView and saving it as a file to the internal storage.